# How to output a separate file per input record in mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce job which consists of just mapper. I'd like this job to output a separate file (whose name is coming from the input record) per input record. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how mapper interface is designed, but nothing stops you from opening a file inside the mapper code and writing something into that file.

You'll probably want to update some counters (using reporter.incrCounter()), so that Hadoop knows that your code is doing something, since you won't be calling output.collect().